# Visual Studio 2015 debugging issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, ef-code-first

Every time I try to debug anything in c# asp.net I get this error.

Error = Unable to evaluate the expression. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80070057.

alongside something like this 
Local = Evaluation of method System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[appname.DataLayer.Entities.GameResultEntity].get_Local() requires use of the static field System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo._currentInfo, which is not available in this context.

[image]

In this case, all I'm doing is adding something to the database (which works) but I get this error when I try to debug anything.
I've restored all the nuget packages, re-installed entity framework, restored my code to a point where everything worked, cleared the cache (recommended in another post) but nothing seems to be working.

Has anybody else encountered this before?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Close visual studio and try deleting (or move) the .suo file located next to the .sln file. Restart. You may need to reset startup project or any other solution setting. http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2014/01/quick-tip-what-to-do-when-visual-studio-freaks-out-and-everything-is-red/

Comment: That's fixed it!!!!!!!!!!!
Cheers, spent far too many hours trying to fix that problem :-)

Comment: Yeah, it's the first thing I do when VS goes bonkers.