# Entity Framework 6.0 - Evaluation of method System.Linq.Queryable.Whewre() requires use of the static field

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6.0 with .NET framework 4.5 inside a SharePoint 2013 project, to get data from a view in a database based on a specific condition.

My Context.cs file looks like this:

```
namespace Clients
    {
        using System;
        using System.Data.Entity;
        using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

        public partial class Clients_ReqsEntities : DbContext
        {
            public Clients_ReqsEntities()
                : base("name=Clients_ReqsEntities")
            {
            }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
            }

            public virtual DbSet<ClientInfo> ClientInfo { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

And my ClientInfo.cs file looks like this:

```
    namespace Clients
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class ClientInfo
    {
        public string ClientTitle { get; set; }
        public string ClientID { get; set; }
        public string ClientUNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am trying to get data from this view based on the ClientUNumber, using this query:

```
 string anyValue = "something"; 
  var client = (context.ClientInfo.Where(c => c.ClientUNumber.Trim() == anyValue)).FirstOrDefault();
```

**The returned value is always "null", however if I run that line of code in Watch window, I am getting this error:**

> Evaluation of method System.Linq.Queryable.Where() requires use of the static field System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[Clients.ClientInfo].MergeAsMethod, which is not available in this context.

I tried using this query too:

```
(from c in context.ClientInfo where c.ClientUNumber.Trim() == anyValue select c).FirstOrDefault();
```

But I am getting the same error.

Some posts suggest to use ToList(), but this will get all records from the DB, and I keep getting Evaluation Timedout. So I don't think this is the right approach. PS: the view has 7k records.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried what was recommended in the first comment of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36455671/visual-studio-2015-debugging-issues) question?

Comment: I think it is the .Trim() causing issues

Comment: Have you tried `c.ClientUNumber.StartsWith(anyValue)`? And try `.FirstOrDefault(c=> c.ClientUNumber.StartsWith(anyValue))` instead of the `Where().FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: @BradleyUffner I don't have any .suo in the folders of my solution. Not even in the same folder as the .sln file.

Comment: @ThomasSchmidt , removing trim() didn't work as well.

Comment: @reckface same problem, I made the code to be: `context.ClientInfo.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClientUNumber.StartsWith(anyvalue)); ` But I got null returned. Whenever I evaluate the expression in Watch, I get the same error.

Comment: @BrittanyRutherford Look for a hidden ".vs" file next to the solution file, and delete that.  The ".suo" is in there somewhere, but deleting the entire ".vs" directory is safe.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I found it, it was hidden. I deleted, deployed again to SharePoint. I tried the same scenario with this code: `context.ClientInfo.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClientUNumber.StartsWith(anyvalue)); ` but am still getting null returned. Although I can see that there's a ClientUNumber with anyvalue that's appearing in the view. I try to execute that line in the Watch window, and I still get the same error: Requires use of the static field ..

Comment: When you say "deployed to sharepoint", does that mean you are using a remote debugging session against the sharepoint server, or is sharepoint installed on your local machine?  Remote debugging could explain the odd behavior you are getting trying to evaluate the linq in the debugging tools.

Comment: @BradleyUffner SharePoint is installed on the same machine. Deploying is just pushing the DLLs to the GAC for SharePoint to see.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the database contains a row matching the criteria you are querying for?  Could you show the row from the database you are expecting it to return?

Comment: @BradleyUffner If I try to run the query in SQL, it works just fine. but not from EF C# code.